# How to determine whether a string has regex metacharacters? (C#)

Tags: c#, regex, string

Does the System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace offer me anything to discover whether an input string has ("abc[0-9]" or "^aeiou$") or has not ("abc123") metacharacters? Or do I have to check manually for non-escaped characters in a certain list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have at least three options:

1. Use [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) and compare the result:

   ```
   private static bool ContainsMetaCharacters(string s)
   {
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
       {
           return false;
       }
       string escaped = Regex.Escape(s);
       return !escaped.Equals(s, StringComparison.Ordinal);
   }
   ```
2. Apply [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) to each character to see if the escaped value is different:

   ```
   private static bool ContainsMetaCharacters(string s)
   {
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
       {
           return false;
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
       {
           if (Regex.Escape(s.Substring(i,1))[0] != s[i])
           {
               return true;
           }
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```
3. Create your own based on the fact that the metachars shouldn't change:

   ```
   private static readonly char[] _MetaChars = 
       new char[] 
       { '\t', '\n', '\f', '\r', 
         ' ', '#', '$', '(', ')', 
         '*', '+', '.', '?', 
         '[', '\\', '^', '{', '|' };

   private static bool ContainsMetaCharacters(string s)
   {
       if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
       {
           return false;
       }
       return s.IndexOfAny(_MetaChars) >= 0;
   }
   ```

The third approach offers more control depending on the [RegexOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) you use in your Regex. For example, if you'll never use RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace, you can remove space as a metachar.

Comment: SWEET! Thanks! By the way, is thanking people in comments within etiquette here, or is it considered unnecessary noise?

Comment: I think comments are fine :) Glad I could help

Comment: I came across this method when I did a deep dive on .net's regular expression engine: http://www.moserware.com/2009/03/how-net-regular-expressions-really-work.html

Comment: Problem: Regex.Escape() escapes spaces; I want "Internet Explorer" to be considered "not a pattern." :(

Comment: This is  subtle thing. Consider:

string hw = "Hello World";
bool hw1 = Regex.IsMatch(hw, "Hello World");
bool hw2 = Regex.IsMatch(hw, "Hello  World", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
bool hw3 = Regex.IsMatch(hw, @"\w+ \w+");
bool hw4 = Regex.IsMatch(hw, @"\w+  \w+");
bool hw5 = Regex.IsMatch(hw, @"\w+  \w+", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

hw1 = true, hw2 = false, hw3=true, hw4=false, hw5=true. Note how in the hw2 context it's false because the Regex tree is looking for a literal. In the hw5 sense it's true because the space is treated as a whitespace metachar.